# Kendo mvvm template with source without a parent element

Tags: kendo-ui, template-engine, kendo-mvvm

I'm trying to bind an array inside a list, but the list needs to have a static element before the array's values.

The fiddle shows the result I'd want, except it currently nests the `li` item.

HTML:

```
<ul id="root">
    <li>blop</li>
    <li data-template="list-template" data-bind="source: products">
    </li>
    <script id="list-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </script>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var vm = kendo.observable({
    products: [
        { id: 1, name: "foo" },
        { id: 2, name: "bar" }
    ]
});

kendo.bind($("#root"), vm);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zpqo80pw/

With KnockoutJS, there was the comment syntax that could be used:

```
<!-- ko: foreach: products -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Is there something similar in Kendo UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to achieve this by extending kendo binding. I put up a small example at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5g7ubm1s/2/) see if it match your requirement.

```
kendo.data.binders.staticValue = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
        refresh: function () {
                debugger;
                var that = this;
                var value = that.bindings["staticValue"].get();
                $(that.element).text(value + $(that.element).text());
            }
        });
```

Comment: I kind of get what you're hinting at, but the JSFiddle is the same as mine. Maybe you forgot to save? I'll look into doing something like that when I get back to that piece of code!

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't update the jsfiddle. here is the updated one http://jsfiddle.net/5g7ubm1s/2/

Comment: Wasn't quite what I wanted, but you lead me to a decent solution. http://jsfiddle.net/5g7ubm1s/4/ This prepends whatever HTML I want after the template has been applied. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question I know, but if this person wanted to do this strictly mvvm, all they needed was to call the same data-bind and data-template but put it on a container element, such as

```
<ul data-template="template-id" data-bind="source: items"></ul>
```

and on the template simply change

```
<script id="list-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>
```

To

```
<script id="list-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>#: staticValue # :: #: name #</li>
</script>
```

anything passed in the model to the template will be available, and there can even be a mixing of data-* injection alongside template #: # syntax